# Dependence of areal velocity on distance between sun and planet

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

We know velocity of a planet in an elliptical orbit is given by:
$$v^2 = GM * (\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a})$$
in an elliptical orbit. [Here r is distance between particle and sun] [source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit)

We also know, areal velocity in an elliptical orbit is given by
$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}vr$$

By putting value of velocity in this equation we find that areal velocity is dependant on r, and thus ever changing(since distance between sun and a planet is also changing)

But keplers second law states that areal velocity of a particle is always constant.

How do I resolve this contradiction? What am I doing wrong? I assumed r would cancel out leaving only contants behind. If I am putting the value of velocity wrong what is the correct one?

Comment: Here's a nice animated diagram showing the relationship between the radius & velocity vectors in an elliptical orbit, plus a few other goodies. https://www.gregegan.net/SCIENCE/LRL/LRL.html

Comment: Definately looks cool, it's apparant here now that r and v are really not perpendicular.

Comment: You may like [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/748130/123208) on the connection between the magnitudes of the tangential velocity, radial velocity, and angular momentum. Also check out the [eccentricity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The areal velocity is
$$
\frac {dA}{dt}= \frac 12 |{\bf r}\times {\bf v}|
$$
and the [vector product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) ${\bf r}\times {\bf v}$  has magnitude  $rv$ only if ${\bf r}$ is at right-angles to ${\bf v}$.

Comment: As far as I am aware though velocity vector is always perpendicular to distance between the sun and planet. Its certainly true for circular orbits, and it seems it applies to elliptical orbits too.

Comment: No. It is not true for ellipses. The velocity vector is necessarily tangent to the ellipse, and  the tanget is everywhere  perpendicular to the radius  only for a circle.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely the error then, as even though areal velocity does depend on the radius when we calculate it for a circle(directly proportional to root r) it doesn't matter as circile had constant radius. While I am not able to find (in general terms)the perpendicular component of the line joining foci with point of contact of tangential vector in a ellipse, my main concern was with the apparant contradiction, I consider the query solved since the alternative proof(dA/dt = L/2m) exists.